# Node.js application to cloud foundry

Tags: eclipse, node.js, cloud-foundry, nodeclipse

I'm using nodeclipse to develop my Node app.
Is there a way to deploy node.js apps to cloud foundry using **eclipse**?
I know about vmc but want to know about alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

No.

As per the tutorial '[Node.js Application Development with Cloud Foundry](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/frameworks/nodejs/nodejs.html)' you can use only vmc.